# Animate view in DialogFragment

Tags: android, view, dialog, android-animation, android-dialogfragment

Well I'm trying to animate a view in DialogFragment when is created and when is dismissed.
But I can figure it out, it's not working for me.
I've tried also all the answers pepole have gave about this here.
I tried : onActivityCreate , setStyle(myCustom), oncreate etc.

I have a custom DialogFragment view.
and i want to animate it when it open and when it closed.

Really need help here.
Thanks ahead.

here is my code :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_page, container, false);
     //Setting up the image by id
     ImageView img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.details_img);
     img.setImageResource(this.imageId);
     //Setting up the title
     TextView tittle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
     tittle.setText(this.title);
     tittle.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
     //Setting up all the details about the item
     TextView details = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.details);
     details.setText(this.details);
     details.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

     return view;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this . and let me know the updates ...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

    layMain = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.layMain);

    TextView btnCancel = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.translate_to_bottom);
                anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
                layMain.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Well i think you did not undrstand me. I want to open the dialogfragment with animation like slide up and when the user go back also animate with slide down. and i dont have any button to listen, the fragment calls up when the user touch row in a list.

Answer (score 3):

Refering to your comment:

> I want to open the dialogfragment with animation like slide up and when the user go back also animate with slide down.

This might be a solution for you:

1) Create animation you like, ie.:

*/res/anim/slide_up.xml*

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />

</set>
```

*/res/anim/slide_down.xml*

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />

</set>
```

2) Create dialog animation style in

*/res/values/styles.xml*

```
    <!-- [...] -->

    <style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

3) Attach style to your dialog:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onActivityCreated(arg0);
    getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
}
```

4) Done. Should work.